# Use XPath 1.0 to find elements with digits and dots

Tags: xpath

I need to find elements containing only digits and dots using XPath 1.0.

For example from elements like these:

```
89.0.1/
89.0.2/
89.0/
89.0b1/
89.0b10/
89.0b11/
something-else/
```

It would only leave these:

```
89.0.1/
89.0.2/
89.0/
```

Comment: Please, add a sample xml. Questions are encouraged to provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

You can match all elements that have only digits and dots (and the `/` char, as in your sample) with this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
self::*[translate(., '0123456789./','')='']
```

If you don't need the elements, but rather just a TRUE/FALSE condition, omit the `self::*[` and `]` part.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Could there also be a way of filtering out values less than for example 89?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your package support [EXSLT](http://exslt.org/).

If it does, you can use regular expressions.

Add a namespace

re = http://exslt.org/regular-expressions

And use the following XPath:

```
s="""
<root>
    <item>89.0.1</item>
    <item>89.0.2</item>
    <item>89.0</item>
    <item>89.0b1</item>
    <item>89.0b10</item>
    <item>89.0b11</item>
    <item>something-else</item>
</root>
"""
ns = {"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"}
from lxml import etree
root = etree.XML(s)
root.xpath("item/text()[re:test(., '^[\d\.]+$')]", namespaces=ns)
```